# postgresql - why is now() is not right after saving?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, timezone, save, region

so it's like this, I have a procedure like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.savetrbankd(
    _transcode text,
    _id integer,
    _expensecode text,
    _debetamt numeric,
    _creditamt numeric)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
Declare 
BEGIN
If _id=0 Then
    INSERT INTO trbankd(transcode,expensecode,ket,debetamt,creditamt)
    VALUES(_transcode,_expensecode,_ket,_debetamt,_creditamt);
Else
    UPDATE trbankd SET 
        expensecode=_expensecode,
        debetamt=_debetamt,
        creditamt=_creditamt,
        LastUpdatedDate=now()
    WHERE transcode=_transcode and id=_id;
END IF;
END;
$BODY$;
```

lets pay attention to field "lastupdateddate" here. The type is timestamp without time zone, and default value of now().

so after inserting/updating the records with this procedure, I tried to query the data again.
so I got :
2021-07-23 23:48:42.805869

but when I insert/update the records, it should be 24 jul 2021 about 1 pm.
so we got the different in timezone about 13-14 hours ?

sure, then when I tried to show timezone, it said it was us/pacific.
then I set the timezone to asia/bangkok (which is my real timezone), with code like : set timezone='Asia/Bangkok'.
the data wasnt changed. it still said lastupdateddate on 23 jul 2021.
Ok, maybe the previous entered data wont change as I used timestamp without time zone type. So I tried to update the data again with the stored procedure, and it still shown 2021-07-24 00:29:23.384443 <= note, that I wasted some time trying to figure out the timezone, so when I updated it the 2nd time here, it's about 1 hour already, and my real time is about 2 pm.

so it's still the same different of about 13-14 hours.
how could I make sure that the data inserted and queried to be the same with the server (which happened to be my computer here).
as an added note, my setting control panel region is us (english), my location has been set to indonesia (gmt +7), and my current time in my computer is right (like I told above it was 1-2pm).

thx in advance

Comment: Note: there is an extra comma after `now()`

Comment: sorry, it was my bad cut. the real stored procedure was actually much longer, so I cut it just to let u know the picture. I have repaired it.
I assured u the real stored procedure ran fine and there's no wrong syntax like this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have discovered is that storing timestamp data in a `timestamp without time zone` field is generally not a good idea, especially when working across time zones. For detailed information on how `timestamp without time zone`(timestamp) and `timestamp with time zone`(timestamptz) work with time stamps see here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html

8.5.1.3. Time Stamps

To illustrate what you are seeing:

```
select '2021-07-23 23:48:42.805869'::timestamp AT time zone 'US/Pacific';
           timezone            
-------------------------------
 2021-07-23 23:48:42.805869-07


select '2021-07-23 23:48:42.805869'::timestamp AT time zone 'US/Pacific' AT time zone 'Asia/Bangkok';
          timezone          
----------------------------
 2021-07-24 13:48:42.805869

---Current time here(I'm in 'US/Pacific')

test(5432)=# show timezone;
  TimeZone  
------------
 US/Pacific
(1 row)

test(5432)=# select now()::timestamp;
            now             
----------------------------
 2021-07-24 08:57:07.780014

                  
test(5432)=# set timezone = 'Asia/Bangkok';
SET
test(5432)=# select now()::timestamp;
            now             
----------------------------
 2021-07-24 22:56:14.659657
```

The `now()` is picking up the time zone set in the server(or reset via the client)and using that to create the timestamp. Since it is being stored to `timestamp` there is no timezone offset. Your choices for dealing with this are:

1. Leave it as it is, `timestamp without time zone` field and `timezone='US/Pacific'`. Do the translation to local time zone as needed.
2. Convert field to `timestamp with time zone`. Before you do this though you will need to be certain you know what the current values actually represent.

Comment: sorry it's been a hectic weeks. so I just check this now.

yes. I know the difference (or I think I did)

what I failed to mention and emphasize is that, this happened at my computer.
my computer is the web server, that I called the procedure from, and that was the source of my confusion because all this happened on 1 computer,my computer.


the now() function should get the time on my computer, and no matter what region it is, it should be the same, because I never changed the region of my computer. I just messed with the region like I said was because of this weird problem.

Comment: Bottom line is `now()` is going to use whatever `TimeZone` is set to at the point it is run. Per your question you said the default time zone in Postgres was set to `US/Pacific`. If you want to make things easier for yourself then use `timestamp with time zone` fields. The timestamp is not actually stored with the time zone, it is just rotated to and stored as `UTC`.  Then you always have a known starting point for the value.